# Meteor.user() returns undefined inside router

Tags: meteor

I have the following setup in Meteor:

When a user hits the root URL and isn't logged in, I show a welcome page.

When a user hits the root URL and IS logged in, I'd like to redirect to the user's 'thing' page.

The problem is, that Meteor.user() is undefined inside the router.

What's the correct way to structure this?

```
<body>
    {{# if currentUser}}
        {{> thing}}
    {{else}}
        {{> welcome}}
    {{/if}}
</body>

var MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
       "": "welcome",
       "/things/:thingId": "thing"
    },
    welcome: function() {
        var user = Meteor.user();
        console.log(user); //undefined
        // Redirect to user's thing
    },
    thing: function(thingId) {
        Session.set("currentThingId", thingId);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your current user is already registrated ? The call to `Meteor.user()` is available on both side (client and server), thus you should have access to the current user instance within the router file. For example I test if the current user is logged in within my router with something like this :

```
var requireLogin = function() { 
    if (! Meteor.user()) {
        if (Meteor.loggingIn())
            this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
        else
            this.render('accessDenied');
            this.stop();
        }
 }

Router.before(requireLogin, {only: 'postSubmit'})
```

Check on the server side in your mongo db :

```
$ meteor mongo
$ >db.users.find().count() // Should be greather than 0
```

Control on the client side. Open a chrome console for example and simply enter :

```
Meteor.user();
null // Means user is currently not logged in 
     // otherwise you should receive a JSON object
```

Comment: Hi, yes the user is definitely registered and signed in (confirmed in Chrome console).